# SQL insert array of string - issues with .join(', ')

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql

Currently I create a string with JavaScript that is used as a SQL query. It reads a number of rows from an Excel sheet and then creates the SQL query by combining all those datapoints with .join(','). I want to add added a column that is a list of tags.

It’s a comma separated array. When my string gets .joined(',')ed it just becomes a string.

Technically its still an array because its being added to my SQL query string as ARRAY['list, of, things'] but I need it to be in my SQL query string as ARRAY['list', 'of', 'things']. Any way to prevent this?

Snip it of code. company[3] is passed in as an array of strings:

```
const tagsPresent = company[3] !== null;

return format(
        `(%L, %L, ${
          tagsPresent ? `'{${company[3]}}'` : 'NULL::text[]'
          // I've also tried 'ARRAY[${company[3]}]' and ARRAY['+ company[3] +']

        })`,
        company[1],
        company[2]
      );
    })
    .join(', ');
```

Comment: SQL Server <> PostgreSQL - please correct you tags.

Comment: Please don't tag conflicting RDBMS. What are you *really* using, SQL Server or PostgreSQL?

Comment: Apologies. I am on postgresql. I thought the syntax to pass in an array would be the same so they were both applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using a map.

```
${
          tagsPresent
            ? `ARRAY[${company[3]
                .split(',')
                .map((tag) => "'" + tag + "'")
                .toString()}]`
            : 'NULL::text[]'
        })
```